# Connecting to remote DB via Spring Boot Application

Tags: mysql

I have an existing JSP/servlet application that I can connect to the remote MochaHost Database when running locally.

I'm migrating that application to a Spring boot/thymeleaf application.  When I use the exact same url/id/pw... I get Access denied for user to database.

I'm running eclipse locally attempting to connect to the remote DB.

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://...mochahost.com:/...
    spring.datasource.username=...
    spring.datasource.password=...
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the properties file allowed me to connect:

```
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.initialize=true
    spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=SELECT 1
    spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=1
```